# Bootstrap well align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

In client script I generate html divs so the result looks like

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="well">
        <div>Content here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is when content is to long. In that case one bigger well makes others to align "behind it". Is there a way to make those wells align where the red arrow points?

[image: well not aligned correctly]

Comment: Are these placed in a `<div class="row">` container?

Comment: Yes the div before col- definition has class="row". So all of them are in one row.

Comment: That's the problem. Each row should occupy at maximum 12 columns.

Comment: write your code in jsfiddle. or dont use rows try to do it with columns

Comment: I assume, since you're using a well, that this is Bootstrap 3. If not, Bootstrap 4 has a [card-column](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-columns) component that more or less gets you this layout.

Comment: Yes it is bootstrap 3. I thought it is rule that each col-xx- definition must be placed in "row" div otherwise something terrible is going to happen. But I can try it without it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt utilizing rows where you want it to break.  You can't have more than 12 columns per row, so your code won't work without breaking it into multiple rows.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="well">
      <div>Content here 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="well">
      <div>Content here 2
        <br/> Roast Duck
        <br/> Roast Duck
        <br/> Roast Duck
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="well">
      <div>Content here 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="well">
      <div>Content here 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="well">
      <div>Content here 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/fcwbt7e6/

Comment: The problem with this solution arises when you add col-sm-6 definition since there are three wells per row, there will be empty space after third well and then next row starts.
In advance I can't tell whether I'll create one well or fifty of them so I am not able to figure out any proper row inserting algorithm.